# How can I save a MomentJS value into a Meteor simple-schema auto-form select list value?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

Trying to get a payment plan going for my Meteor app currently.
When a user creates a new post, I want to make options for an expiry date on the post.

This is what my attempt in simple-schema currently looks like-

```
    expiryDate: {
  type: String,
  allowedValues: ['One Month ($35/month)', 'Two Months ($30/month)', 'Three Months ($25/month)'],
  autoform: {
    options: [
      {label: "One Month ($35/month)", value: moment().add(30, 'days');},
      {label: "Two Months ($30/month)", value: moment().add(60, 'days');},
      {label: "Three Months ($25/month)", value: moment().add(90, 'days');}
    ]
  }
},
```

This obviously doesn't work, is there a way I can properly do this?

Comment: add `.toDate()` to the end of each value... `moment().add(30, 'days').toDate()`

Comment: However, the `allowedValues` array won't work, the way you have it set up. It's be better to use the `custom` function to validate the selected value, to make sure it's within the desired range.

Comment: @BrianShamblen hmmm okay. So force validation against the values ?
I'll give it a shot, still a little sketchy with my simple-schema and autoform currently. Thanks though!

Comment: @BrianShamblen hey, so I didn't go the custom validation route as I'm a little confused as to how to do that.
Uncaught Error: Unexpected object in htmljs in toText: Tue Apr 05 2016 17:29:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)
What I see from this is that my date is working properly (30 days from now). This is in my helper code - 
        options: [
          {label: "1 Month ($35/month)", value: moment().add(30, 'days').toDate()},
          {label: "2 Months ($30/month)", value: moment().add(60, 'days').toDate()}

Comment: if you want to store the value as a `Date` object, change the `type` to `Date` and remove the 'allowedValues' validation. That should allow you to get the data into the database. From there you can add the 'custom' validation to make sure the values are accurate, which is really just to prevent someone from manually setting the value on the client side.